# ImageMagick command equivalent for a CSS brighten + blur filter

Tags: css, imagemagick, filtering, minimagick

I am having a lot of trouble trying to understand the CSS rules of `filter brightness / blur` to replicate the same effect on the original image directly via ImageMagic.

[The overall look'n'feel I'm trying to achieve](https://www.myjobglasses.com/search?query=cyril%20my%20job%20glasses&page=1&size=12) : each avatar is on a background image that is actually the same avatar, but blurred and darkened. I'm trying to craft that background using the original image.

The CSS for the background

```
.professional-card .header .avatar-background {
    width: 110%;
    height: 110%;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-filter: blur(10px) brightness(50%);
    filter: blur(10px) brightness(50%);
```

To begin with, I'm not sure how to convert this `blur(10px)` into ImageMagick's [`blur`](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#blur) with `radiusxsigma` I tried using something like `blur: [0, 12]` but doesn't seem to quite make it

Next I can't figure out what the `brightness(50%)` actually converts to. I've tried various stuff, `gamma`, `modulate` and the latest that byt the sound of it should be what shoud work best `img.brightness_contrast(-50)`.

But the final image I get (combined with the blur) doesn't get the same feeling : https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcbwW.jpg

Another thing I noticed : the order of the filters doesn't seem to matter on the browsers `blur(10px) brightness(50%)` == `brightness(50%) blur(10px)` but it does on imagemagick (https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cpab.jpg when blurring is done before darkening). Mathematically speaking it does make sense that blurring/darkening are not commutative that's why Im' starting to think the browsers' way of filtering is maybe not a simple operation...?

*sidenote: I'm having some troubles making the background image IE11 and Outlook compatible, so I need to generate the same image backend-side so I can just use a simple background image without any CSS/filter needed client-side*

Comment: With most css options it does not seem to matter which order you put them in; as you say there could be something going on internally that puts them in the correct order. There are a lot of examples of Imagemagick use here: https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Imagemagick 6.9.9.30 Q16 Mac OSX Sierra. You do not say what version of Imagemagick you are using!

Original:

[image]

Looking at the CSS filter documentation for blur and brightness at https://drafts.fxtf.org/filter-effects/#ShorthandEquivalents, I see that their brightness (slope of straight line transfer function) is similar to Imagemagick +level for darkening by 50% and their blur is a gaussian blur with the value corresponding to the standard deviation (or sigma), so similar to Imagemagick's -blur (faster) or -gaussian-blur (slower).

So in principal, this should be the same as your CSS code

```
convert cyril.jpg -blur 0x10 +level 0x50% cyril_blur_level.png
```

[image]

The order is not important. So this is the same.

convert cyril.jpg +level 0x50% -blur 0x10 cyril_blur_level2.png

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks for the detailed answer ! I actually have (in production) Amazon Linux machines with imagemagick version: ImageMagick 6.7.8-9 2016-06-22 Q16 and ersion 6.5.9 on my local macOS. I'll try to upgrade  the versions and use your suggestion tomorrow of using `level` tomorrow to see what it looks like on both development and production environment

Comment: Unless there is a bug in either of your versions, my command should work fine. Although 6.5.9 is terribly old (about 450 versions old). You should be able to upgrade your Mac using Homebrew (for IM 6 or IM 7) or MacPorts for IM 6 only. Or if on High Sierra, you can install the Mac binary of imagemagick from http://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#macosx. IM 6.7.8.9 is also old (about 230 version), but should work. I do not know if Amazon has more current version.

Comment: @fmw42 Do you know where I can find the imagemagick command equivalent for all css filters ?

Comment: I do not know what all the CSS filters are. Each one would need to be prototyped to develop an equivalent. So, sorry, I do not know the equivalents off-hand. I have not seen anyone develop them and publish them.